# Cómo generar una lista de elementos basado en un array de objetos por clave

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo generar una nueva lista (array) cuyos elementos sean el valor de un indice específico?

Ejemplo, tengo este array:

```
listas = [
{
    "PRF_NOMBRE_PREDIO": "INVERSIONES MINDALA 2012",
    "PRF_CIUDAD": "No Registra",
    "PRF_DEPARTAMENTO": "No Registra",
    "PRF_VEREDA": "No Registra"
},
{
    "PRF_NOMBRE_PREDIO": "PLANTACION LOTE 2013",
    "PRF_CIUDAD": "No Registra",
    "PRF_DEPARTAMENTO": "No Registra",
    "PRF_VEREDA": "No Registra"
},
{
    "PRF_NOMBRE_PREDIO": "La Caimanera",
    "PRF_CIUDAD": "No Registra",
    "PRF_DEPARTAMENTO": "No Registra",
    "PRF_VEREDA": "No Registra"
}]
```

¿Es posible filtrar solo los valores que pertenezcan al índice `PRF_NOMBRE_PREDIO` sin la necesidad de usar **for**?

Este es el resultado que busco:

```
nuevaLista = [
    "INVERSIONES MINDALA 2012",
    "PLANTACION LOTE 2013",
    "PLANTACION LOTE 2013"
]
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? tendrías que apoyarte en un ejemplo verificable https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Puedes usar la función `map` de los arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map `const nuevaLista = listas.map(elemento => elemento['PRF_NOMBRE_PREDIO']);`

Answer (score 3):

Como te lo indicaron en los comentarios, lo puedes lograr con un `map`.

La función [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) retorna una nueva lista con los valores que resuelven en `true` en la condición. En este caso la condición es que retorne el `valor` del `key` `obj['PRF_NOMBRE_PREDIO']`, si ese `key` no existen en un objeto se retorna `null`.

```js
let result = listas.map(obj => obj['PRF_NOMBRE_PREDIO'])

console.log(result) // ["INVERSIONES MINDALA 2012","PLANTACION LOTE 2013","PLANTACION LOTE 2013"]
```